# C project files and modular organization

Tags: c

> C project files and modular organization
>
> I been searching and can not find sane answers(examples without the technical jargon of a newish programmer) of organization of C projects.
>
> I may be me having issues by not searching the technical word to describe this. (re-factoring, modular programming and project organization?)
>
> Example of how I would like to organize a project, I'm just confused on header definition hierarchy and scopes between source/header files.

--main.c--

```
#include “project_headers.h”

int main(void)
{
    int errorCode = runProgram();
    if(errorCode != 0)
    {
        storeError(“Error while running program”, errorCode);
    }
return errorCode;
}
```

--project_headers.h--

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// and any other header I might need
```

--runprogram.c--

```
#include “project_headers.h”

int runProgram()
{
    int running = 1;
    int errorCode = 0;

    if(initialize() == 1)
    {
        errorCode = 5567;
        storeError(“Error while initializing”, errorCode);
        running = 0;
    {

    while(running == 1)
    {
        if(events() != 0)....  //.... = same as initialize() but different error codes
        if(logic() != 0)....
        if(render() != 0)....
    {
    if(cleanupAndShutdown() != 0)....
    return errorCode;
}
```

--initialize.c--

```
#include “project_headers.h”
int initSDLstuff()
{
}

int initWindow()
{
}

int initialize()
{
    int errorCode = 0;
    if(initSDLstuff() != 0)....
    if(initWindow() != 0)....
    return errorCode;
}
```

This of coarse doesn't work, I tried it. Problems with undefined references out of scope etc.

I'm a big fan of getting it right the first time and way over think things and got into reading threads, articles, how too's and even debates like K&R style is the only way vs other.

I don't want this to turn to an opinionated answer and will try to narrow it down.

### I want my coding in 'C' to be modern, modular, simple and elegant

I would like to be able to write code outside of tutorials that any team, employee or human would look at and say! Wow nice job, I wanted to modify X and everything works still.

I looked for some good source code for references and people said to look at 'Doom' or the Linux kernel and found they are a little over my head for my experience and maybe not so much a 'modern' style.

I'm not looking for super optimized code that's just obfuscated and hard on the eye. If anyone knows any references of great 'C' only projects that would be great. Some example projects that may interest me would be an image loader/saver, a calculator, simple 3d model viewer, a simple text editor able to save and load. I have looked at lot's of source code but it is hard for an inexperienced programmer to tell what are good and bad practices and I really don't want to fix bad habits.

Sorry for the long winded question, and tried my best to narrow it down so it is not opinionated.

### 1. C project files and modular organization? (could use my sample code as example)

### 2. Good simple C projects/source that are of the nature of  modern, modular, simple and elegant?

Thanks

Comment: How much over-engineering do you want to do?

Comment: @self I believe that is my problem, I just want to get it right and not be called one of those BAD programmers. Not overly engineered just a good work-flow and style.

Comment: Why does it "of course not work"? I'm assuming you put all your function prototypes in the header file, too, right?

Comment: @ooga your right! But the question is not really about this code really working or not it's more of where/how should I organize function prototypes not use globals or so I'm taught. Either I have one confusing giant header file with all directives, macro's, prototypes and global variables or struggle with pointer parameters and file organization. References of great projects of experienced programmers on what is the holy grails would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **non-technical explanation of project layout**.

**(1.)** All of the jargon can be boiled down to **keeping your code clean, readable and maintainable** so navigating a 100,000 (or 1,000,000) line source doesn't interfere with your coding thought process. If you are getting lost in your source, it's time to think about pairing things down and putting like code in separate files.

**(2.)** What goes where? Well.., **keep stuff that is logically related together**. If you have a short project, then there may be no need to split the code up at all. If on the other-hand you are using an abstract data structure for data handling (e.g a `linked-list`, etc.), then it will make sense to split the data-handling structures and function off into a separate header and source so your main source isn't cluttered with 1000 lines of list manipulation code. If it is a scientific project with functions related to orbital mechanics, then it would make sense to split those routines off as well. Basic rule **keep stuff that goes together -- together.** Not only does this promote **maintainability**, but it promotes **reusability** as well. If you have another project that needs the same orbital mechanics routines, you can reuse the source and header you have already created, rather than reinventing the wheel each time.

**(3.)** As your custom code base grows, it may make sense to **start grouping like functions together in their own files, which you can later turn into libraries**, or that you can use whenever. If you have a collection of functions that provide `binary output representation` and/or handled `bit operations`, those may make sense to you to keep together. Same with your `file/directory` routines. Same with your `string manipulations` routines. The bottom line **whatever logical groupings make sense to you**, and help **keep your code clean and maintainable** make sense to be kept together.

**(4.)** Another consideration is **data hiding/protection & function access**. By splitting your data into separate headers, you can to some extent control in C what functions and what source files have access to what data by whether you make that data available through header inclusion. For an extreme example of the extent to which this can be used, see [**Object oriented programming with ANSI-C**](https://ritdml.rit.edu/handle/1850/8544).

**(5.)** **When is a good time to split things up?** Here again, when you start a project, you either have those pieces you have already split up that you plan on using, that you bring in, or you find yourself prototyping from basically 1 file. As that file grows, when you get to the point that you are spending brain-power hunting/searching through your file for functionX or variableY, then it is probably time to look and see if you can clean up your code and make life easier by collecting the like code into a separate file. You are the judge. If you are one of those people that can slice/dice 100,000 lines without ever losing track of the logic-flow, locations, etc., then you won't get to the "It might make sense to collect and separate" point much later than others. It's what works for you.

There are other considerations, **no doubt 6-500 more**, but that is the jest of why you would want to split your code up between various headers and source files. You often see examples when you are learning, of code nicely split between files where there is no other reason but to show it can be done behind it. If you have 27 lines of code in 3 functions and 2 variables, there is no reason to split anything up, but you will find example, after example, that does it -- just to show what you can do to compartmentalize your data and code. That doesn't mean you need to start splitting when you hit line 28. Do what works for you.

Comment: @Mr. Rankin Thank you for your detailed answer. Not only for the non-technical jargon but also providing an extreme example and on the same note, to do what is comfortable.  I believe I maybe over thinking/engineering and your answer gave me some confidence to get back on track.

Comment: Glad I can help. C is an exact language, you should continue to strive to understand it in depth. (this just happens to be one part where you have flexibility) For the rest of it -- keep attacking it like you attacked this question and you will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is relatively simple, but the details are up to you, the system designer:

1. create a .h file for each and every .c file
2. only include a specific header file when it is needed
3. from a top level project directory,

   - create a sub directory that include all the .h files (`include` is a common name)
   - create a sub directory that include all the .c files (`src` is a common name)
4. in your `makefile`, in the top level project directory,

   - define a macro that has the path to the .h file(s)
   - define a macro that has the path to the source file(s)
   - define a macro that has the path to where the .o files are to be placed
   - define a macro to where any other files are to be kept 
       (for instance .d dependency files)
   - use those macros in the gcc compile statements
   - use the .o macro in the gcc linker statements

Comment: "create a .h file for each and every .c file" - really? That doesnt make any sense, typically there are one or 2 h files for a whole project - the rest of the advice is spot on

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for your swift answer! Quick questions, probley just reading it wrong. 1. and 2. points you made seam to contradict each other or do you mean only include library header files(SDL.h as an example) when needed? Is this a system designer approach or general consciences. Also creating a separate header for each *.c do I end up putting all the header directives in main for X prototypes used in main or them all that are related to Z project?

Comment: @pm100:  If you define only 1 or 2 header files,  Then any single file being changed, say to have a new (or modified) interface (function change) will result in the appropriate header file being changed.  That results in the whole project being re-compiled.  That (whole project being re-compiled) is a major waste of resources.  Especially as the reality is (usually) only a couple of source files actually need to be changed.  Just think of how That effects a project that contains hundreds (or even thousands) of source files

Comment: @abflett:  I'm saying, a separate header files for each source file.  Then only include a header file where it is actually needed.  The idea is to minimize the amount of re-compiling that is needed for a change to the code